# Windows Phone: How to add custom confirmation dialog in OnBackKeyPress

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone, windows-phone-toolkit

I am going to implement custom confirmation dialog in `OnBackKeyPress` method. It is easy to do with native message box:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnBackKeyPress(e);

  MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Text");

  if(result==MessageBoxResult.OK)
  {
    e.Cancel = true;
  }
}
```

It works, but I dislike limitation with two buttons so I am looking for something else.

I have checked WPtoolkit:

```
private bool m_cansel = false;
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnBackKeyPress(e);

  if (!m_cansel)
  {
    e.Cancel = true;
    m_cansel = true;
    var messageBox = new CustomMessageBox
      {
        Title = "Title",
        Message = "Message",
        RightButtonContent = "aas",
        IsLeftButtonEnabled = false,
      };
    messageBox.Dismissed += (sender, args) =>
      {
      };
    messageBox.Show();
  }
}
```

And Coding4Fun:

```
private bool m_cansel = false;
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnBackKeyPress(e);

  if (!m_cansel)
  {
    e.Cancel = true;
    m_cansel = true;
    var messageBox = new MessagePrompt 
      {
        Title = "Title",
        Message = "Message",
      };
    messageBox.Completed += (sender, args) =>
      {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
      };
    messageBox.Show();
}
```

Both looks good, but don't work in `OnBackKeyPress` method (show and immediately disappear without any my action).

Moreover, I've tried XNA:

```
private bool m_cansel = false;
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnBackKeyPress(e);

  if (!m_cansel)
  {
    e.Cancel = true;
    m_cansel = true;
    Guide.BeginShowMessageBox("Version of Windows", "Pick a version of Windows.",
                              new List<string> {"Vista", "Seven"}, 0, MessageBoxIcon.Error,
                              asyncResult =>
                                {
                                  int? returned = Guide.EndShowMessageBox(asyncResult);
                                }, null);
  }
}
```

It works as I expected (has customs in `OnBackKeyPress` method), but I don't sure that using XNA inside Silverlight app is good practice.

So, I am looking a way to use WPtoolkit or Coding4Fun windows inside `OnBackKeyPress` method or any explanation about using XNA inside Silverlight app (any recomendation or info about approval such kind app by store).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the dispatcher to delay the messagebox until you get out of the OnBackKeyPress event, and it should work:

```
private bool m_cansel = false;
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnBackKeyPress(e);

    if (!m_cansel)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        m_cansel = true;
        var messageBox = new CustomMessageBox
            {
                Title = "Title",
                Message = "Message",
                RightButtonContent = "aas",
                IsLeftButtonEnabled = false,
            };
        messageBox.Dismissed += (sender, args) =>
            {
            };

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(messageBox.Show);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the BackKeyPress event instead of overriding the OnBackKeyPress method. This way, you don't need to use the dispatcher:

```
privatevoid Page_BackKeyPress(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (!m_cansel)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        m_cansel = true;
        var messageBox = new CustomMessageBox
        {
            Title = "Title",
            Message = "Message",
            RightButtonContent = "aas",
            IsLeftButtonEnabled = false,
        };
        messageBox.Dismissed += (s, args) =>
        {
        };

        messageBox.Show();
    }
}
```

And in the XAML:

```
BackKeyPress="Page_BackKeyPress"
```